# Finding node-dispoint paths from A to B

Tags: algorithm, graph, discrete-mathematics

This is the problem I got stumped on the exam:

Given a directed graph G = (V,E), and let A and B be partition of V(union of A and B is V and they are disjoint). I want to find a set of paths such that:

1) Every path contains exactly one node in A

2) Each node in A is the first node of corresponding path

3) For each path, the last node is in B

4) All paths are node-disjoint

Given A,B, and G=(B,E), I have to design a poly-time algorithm to decide whether such a set of paths exist.

The observation I made is that if I have a cut (A,B) and then look at the number of arcs going from A to B, then the number of arcs must be at least |A| for such a set of paths to exist. Also, every node in A must be adjacent to at least one of nodes in B. Also, once a path crosses the cut from A to B, you can't cross from B to A because of the constraint (1), but what's difficult is how to find node-disjoint paths among the vertices in B... How should I approach this?

Comment: From your description, there is a solution iff every node in A is adjacent to a node in B, and any selection of A->B edges that covers A is a valid set of (length=1) paths.   It makes me think you made a mistake describing the problem.

Comment: Yea stupid mistake. I just answered my own question if it were asking for edge-disjoint paths. I made the correction into node-disjoint paths instead.

Comment: Actually I think I get it. I was thinking about this for a while; a set of such node-disjoint paths exist iff every node in A can be matched with a node in B (where a matching covers A). Then I can just construct a bipartite graph from G with bipartition (A,B) preserving only edges going from A to B, then turn this graph into network flow problem. If the max flow is |A|, then every node A is matched.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem